# Can you transform a pair of numbers to equal each other based on given rules?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, python

Given two different positive integers, $a$ and $b$, can they ever equal each other given the following rules for transforming them (written in python-esque pseudocode):

```
if a < b:
  a = 2a
  b = b-a
elif a > b:
  b = 2b
  a = a-b
else: 
  return True
```

Example of a pair that will equal:

```
11,21
22,10
12,20
24,8
16,16
```

And an example of a pair that will never equal each other:

```
1,4
2,3
4,1
3,2
1,4
repeating...
```

So my question is, can you tell that two numbers will equal without running through a function similar to the one above and looking for equality or an infinite loop?

I started approaching this by graphing all combinations of two numbers ($a$ on the y-axis and $b$ on the x-axis): the yellow points indicating pairs that will equal each other. [See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HM2tZ.png).This *was* computed with a modification of the above function. But it would be great not to have to do this because it quickly becomes intractable.

I can clearly see a pattern and now I'm trying to figure out the rules for computing it. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Does this form of problem have a name or is there a field of mathematics that would contain the answer?

Comment: Please don't say "equal each other".  Having the program return true is not the same thing as being equal. Two different numbers will never equal each other.  Come up with a different term for returning true.

Comment: Thanks, hope my edit clarifies this.

Comment: My answer is incorrect as @Daniel Mathias' comment shows.  It gives equations for the dense lines in your plot.  It would be helpful to post some of the values not on dense lines.  It looks like the undense lines have rational slopes, maybe $\frac 74$ or something so there is a dot every $4$ numbers.  Also see my comment to P Vanchinathan's answer.  In usual computer programming the variable is replaced immediately but in your pseudocode the second line under the if is executed with the old value of $a,b$, not the value that came from the line above.

Comment: I believe the criterion is that $\frac {a+b}{\gcd(a,b)}$ is a power of $2$.  You could check that with your program.

Answer (score 1):

Write $a$ and $b$ in binary.  If $\gcd(a,b)=1$ they become equal (and it returns True the next time) if $a+b$ is a power of $2$. If $\gcd(a,b) \gt 1$, they become equal if $\frac {a+b}{\gcd(a,b)}$ is a power of $2$.  In other cases they will cycle.

Added:  the chain starting with $11,21$, written in binary goes
$$01011,10101\\
11010,01010\\
01100,10100\\
11000,01000\\
10000,10000\\
10000,00000$$
The chain starting with $35,77$ goes
$$010011,101101\\
100110,101010\\
11100,1010100\\
111000,111000\\
1110000,0000000$$

Note how the rightmost ones move left once per iteration.

To prove this, represent $a,b$ as $mp,mq$ with $p,q$ coprime and $p \lt q$.  Then the next iteration is $2a, 2^n-2a$, so the sum is maintained.  If $2^k$ is the highest power of $2$ that divides $a,b$, after one iteration $2^{k+1}$ divides both numbers.  If $a,b$ are common multiples of an odd number, that is maintained by the iteration.  The $\gcd$ doubles each iteration until it is $\frac 12(a+b)$.  We can only get to $a=b$ if the sum is $2^n\gcd(a,b)$

Comment: Thanks a million for your answers, it'll take me a bit to wrap my head around it. I'll accept then, thanks.

Comment: $a+b=2^n$ is not the only condition that leads to equality

Comment: @DanielMathias:  Yes, I find $(15,33)$ does, too.  Working on it.  I think we need the bitwise OR of $a$ and $b$ to be of the form $00000011111111000000$ where we need any number of leading zeros, at least one $1$, and at least one $0$.   The leading zeros are what spoil my $2^n$ claim.  Thanks.

Comment: The lines in the image are clear. They include $(x,3x)$, $(x,7x)$, $(x,15x)$, $(3x,5x)$ and $(5x,11x)$. There will be an infinite number of these.

Answer (score 1):

Your (Python) code fragment seems to be the only definition of your function.
But the output run you show does not seem to be from the given code. Possibly you are executing it in your head using the correct definition but I can only go by your code.

Starting with initial values a = 11, b = 21.
First we double the smaller number and set "a" to be that value.
So "a" becomes  22. Immediately b is decreased by "a" . So "b" should get the new value $21 -22 = -1$. Once one number is negative and another is positive, we will be caught in an infinite loop. (Negative number becomes more negative, and positive number becomes bigger and bigger).

Please  specify function mathematically instead of through any code.

Comment: The code fragment is meant to have both lines after the if executed with the old values of the variables, so you start with $(a,b)$ and $a \lt b$ you go to $(2a, b-a)$